# redisai Client password/auth process

Tags: python, authentication, redis

I am trying to connect to a redisai server through the redisai-py Client. The server is password protected and the Client is passed host, port, and password as arguments. However, the client times out on a tensorset/get even though it returns a connection object.

```
import redisai
r = redisai.Client(host='<host>', port=<port>, password='<password>')
```

in redis-cli, you would

```
redis-cli
auth <password>
...
```

which works just fine. There doesn't seem to be a way to perform this action through a redisai-py Client despite it extending the StrictRedis class. Since the Client won't connect without authentication, I cannot access the data.

Comment: Can you try `r.ping()` to make sure you can communicate to the remote? The idea here is that `redisai.Client` is a child class of python redis Client. And the timeout usually means the local is not able to communicate to the remote. I am trying to understand whether it's an issue with redisai client or an issue with communication itself

Comment: @hhsecond thanks for following up: r.ping() also times out too. I can connect to the remote redis database from the same VM which the python client is failing with ```redis-cli -h <host>```. If I run the python client in the same VM as the redis db, it also cannot connect.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue at all. Just a follow-up question: When you say you can connect to the remote using `redis-cli -h <host>`, did you mean you can do `ping` also from `redis-cli`? Because, on connection `redis-cli` doesn't verify the authentication. It only happens when you do an action, like `ping` or `tensorset` etc

Comment: I implemented the workaround posted below in the answers. I could never get proper authentication working with the redisai Client on an exposed but requirepass redisai database. 

But yes, I could do a ping command from the redis-cli. Like my solution below, I am curious if dropping the port argument from the connection object might solve my problem. I will test later and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to accessing the redisai database involved creating inbound port rules focused directly around the VNet the Azure VM nodes were located on.

When connecting with redisai Client, the private IP address is used and the argument for port is left out.

```
import redisai

r = redisai.Client(host=<Private IP>)
r.ping()
# PONG
```

The primary node inbound port rules:
[image: primary_node_inbound_port_rules]

Worker inbound port rule:
[image: worker_inbound_port_rule]

However, this does not solve the issue around the client hanging and providing authentication when the redisai database is exposed but requires a password.